# Finding the largest variable in a list while the output is still a variable not a number

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I have been trying to make a code which sorts a list of variables. I am aware it is possible to do this in many ways, including bubble sort, which I'm trying to use. However when I use bubble sort to sort my list the output is always in numbers instead of the variable names. Sorry if the answer is obvious, I am new to Python.

```
A = 5
B = 7
c= 8
def bubblesort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

alist = [B,A,c]
bubblesort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Comment: Step 1 of debugging: Remove the `bubblesort(alist)` from your code and see what happens. Step 2 of debugging: Ask yourself why `print(alist)` doesn't literally print the text "alist".

Comment: Python doesn't work with references, there's not a variable class. And you can sort a list using `sorted(alist)`

Comment: simplified: you have ``a=1;print(a)`` and expect Python to print ``a`` instead of ``1`` - but that's not how it works.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you expect. Sorting a list of numbers will give you a list of numbers, not a list of variables. You should use a dictionary if you want to map key:value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = {5: 'A', 7: 'B', 8: 'c'}
print([alist[item] for item in sorted(alist)])
```

Comment: What if the list contains two equal numbers?

Comment: It can be trivially altered to store values as a `list of string` as opposed to a string.